# Unzip in Unix and renaming the files

Tags: shell, files

```
    ./zips/
a.zip - contains bla.txt , cla.txt
b.zip - contains bla.txt, cla.txt
c.zip - contains somethingelse.txt, this.xls
d.zip - contains bla.txt
...   - ...
```

Need output in folder /tmp/

```
a_bla.txt
a_cla.txt
b_bla.txt
b_cla.txt
c_somethingelse.txt
c_this.xls

  Tried mkdir tmp
  for f in *.zip; do unzip "$f" -d tmp && mv tmp/* "${f%.zip}.txt"; done
  rmdir tmp
```

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to click [edit] and show us what you have tried so far, and show the result?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for zip in *.zip; do bsdtar -xvf "$zip" -C /tmp -"s/^/${zip%.zip}_/"; done
```

Comment: -bash: bsdtar: command not found

Comment: @user2292524, if your sysadmin could be convinced to install `unzip` (more like a port of a MS-DOS command!), I'm sure they can be convinced to install `bsdtar`, a proper Unix-style archive manipulator, not limited to PKZIP files and with an interface not as alien to Unix as pkzip's